# After fetch and merge my master and origin/master is different however I'm getting the message 'Already up to date'

Tags: git, github

I just recently started learning GIT and I'm running into a situation I just can't figure out.

I basically wanted to see how I can pull the changes from a remote master branch and merge with my own master so I can see how I'd get changes from the team in an actual dev shop.

While on master, I created and checked out a branch called 'test'. I added 'TestTestTest.txt', added and commited and then checked out master. The file 'TestTestTest.txt' wasn't there like I expected. I accidentally merged the test branch to master but deleted 'TestTestTest.html and then removed and committed. Anyways I pushed the branch 'test' to github, created a pull request to merge the branch test to master and then merged, so in essence origin/master was different than my local master. Origin/Master has the file 'TestTestTest.html' and my local master does not.

Ok here is where I'm confused. I ran:

```
git fetch origin master
```

and then I ran:

`git diff master origin/master` and I got:

```
diff --git a/TESTTESTTEST.txt b/TESTTESTTEST.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

ok awesome. When I ran:

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
```

I'm getting:

```
Already up to date
```

This doesn't really make sense to me because my local master and the remote master are different.

If I run:

```
git checkout origin/master 
git log --pretty=oneline
```

I get:

```
e1e5344f45bb0301c9e1671b74a3803f5b29fc40 (HEAD, origin/master) Merge pull request #1 from oystagoymp/test
66338a8823d2a8bba3f1f076a45265e4dfca42d6 (origin/test, test) Added a test message to see if it works when I pull from master
1a223cbf5243ae004e2d2b6156470274bb626f7e (backup) added tabs functionality
8943feab9a240339b70b4d19abfdea40a51810f7 Created template and tabs page
263a4bd65e1dacac84748ec941217839dc4435e0 Event emitting
2f4c6247a2229edf22ce09b72a6a06f8de8491df toggle functionality implemented
4ddd0442b36631460ec720d4b96ca2fb6fd558a8 working message component - basic
ad6c716d9558b7cefbae6422b78a916f3e19e37f Added empty message html page
2d2997c5d0128254b7385cb1bb80282bfc679b4a First component including javascript and edited source file
92b5a02b51512d0269de2ad604057f079f99e999 Working tasks program with add
785516c8d4afa5ab53d51d427dad20f392eca403 commiting tasks after filter and incomplete add
337baa1d13a434c1fe18d78bf436da7e0ec8e602 Initial commit of first vue code file
```

If I run:

```
git checkout master
git log --pretty=oneline
```

I get:

```
26b19af199eaa20a280e22513c97e469a7d8b5da (HEAD -> master) Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
e1e5344f45bb0301c9e1671b74a3803f5b29fc40 (origin/master) Merge pull request #1 from oystagoymp/test
460c60e90e6762e89544920a2ced3698840b0f74 removed TestTestTEst.txt
66338a8823d2a8bba3f1f076a45265e4dfca42d6 (origin/test, test) Added a test message to see if it works when I pull from master
1a223cbf5243ae004e2d2b6156470274bb626f7e (backup) added tabs functionality
8943feab9a240339b70b4d19abfdea40a51810f7 Created template and tabs page
263a4bd65e1dacac84748ec941217839dc4435e0 Event emitting
2f4c6247a2229edf22ce09b72a6a06f8de8491df toggle functionality implemented
4ddd0442b36631460ec720d4b96ca2fb6fd558a8 working message component - basic
ad6c716d9558b7cefbae6422b78a916f3e19e37f Added empty message html page
2d2997c5d0128254b7385cb1bb80282bfc679b4a First component including javascript and edited source file
92b5a02b51512d0269de2ad604057f079f99e999 Working tasks program with add
785516c8d4afa5ab53d51d427dad20f392eca403 commiting tasks after filter and incomplete add
337baa1d13a434c1fe18d78bf436da7e0ec8e602 Initial commit of first vue code file
```

Does anyone have any idea why GIT thinks my local master is up to date? I fell like there is something integral to GIT that I'm not understanding.

Thanks!

Comment: it allwo you to push your local git to the remote ?

Comment: Your local `master` is indeed up to date; both branches are at `e1e5344f45bb0301c9e1671b74a3803f5b29fc40` (excluding the additional line where you simply pulled the origin into your local). You've simply removed the `.txt` file from your local copy, and not yet committed that change back to the origin. Also, you should never *ever* need to `checkout` the `origin`; your local `master` branch is tracking it. Instead you should be running `pull` before you make any changes, and then simply commit back to your local branch (the origin will receive the changes, as they track each other).

Comment: @ObsidianAge If I removed the file from another remote branch (test) and then merged with the remote master via a pull request, and then fetched and merged. Why would they be up to date. It seems like the remote master would have an additional merge and they wouldn't be in sync.

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I was able to push it and it deleted TestTestTest.txt from origin/master

Comment: from what you said above, you will want to merge master and test so that you can have the newly added file `TESTTESTTEST.txt` right?

Answer (score 1):

Your `master`(26b19af1) branch already sits on top of `origin/master`(e1e5344f) so it is `Already up to date`. This just means that `master` already has all the commits which exists in `origin/master`.

Since `master` and `origin/master` do not refer to the same hash revision, `git diff` will show differences.